# How to post an array to mvc controller

Tags: arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to post java script object to mvc controller

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#my_table_1').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "search": true,
            "pageLength": 100
});
var d = '';
var data3 = table.on('search.dt', function () {
    //number of filtered rows
    //  console.log(table.rows({ filter: 'applied' }).nodes().length);
    //filtered rows data as arrays
    d = table.rows({ filter: 'applied' }).data()
});
console.log(table.rows({ filter: 'applied' }).data());
$('#excel2').click(function (e) {
    //var data3 = table.on('search.dt', function () {         
    //    console.log(table.rows({ filter: 'applied' }).data());
    //    console.log(data3);
    //});
    console.log(d);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Administrator/TestDownload',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {data:d},
        cache: false

    }).done(function (response) {
        alert(d);
       });
    });
});
```

//Controller code:

```
public JsonResult TestDownload(String[] data)
    {
        return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I am getting null in controller as a data parameter

Expected: Want to get data object from view to controller as a parameter in controller.

Actual: Data parameter in controller is null

Comment: Can you post console log of d variable

Answer (score 1):

An example that works:

```
        var test = ["This", "is", "a", "test"];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            url: "Administrator/TestDownload",
            data: { array: test }
            }
        });
```

The controller(in VB.net):

```
Function TestDownload(array As String()) As ActionResult
//do something
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check your d variable correct array format.

I tested in my side with `var d = ["test",2,3]` and in controller it get correct data.

```
$('#excel2').click(function (e) {
    //var data3 = table.on('search.dt', function () {         
    //    console.log(table.rows({ filter: 'applied' }).data());
    //    console.log(data3);
    //});
    d = ["test",2,3]
    console.log(d);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Administrator/TestDownload',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {data:d},
        cache: false

    }).done(function (response) {
        alert(d);
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try `stringifying` the data and setting the `contentType`

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Administrator/TestDownload',
    data: JSON.stringify({data:d}), // use JSON stringify
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //add this
    cache: false    
}).done(function (response) {
    alert(d);
   });
});
```